# change Radiogroup circle colors

Tags: android

I have a radiogroup and trying to change the circle colors.  My code is below but running into an issue getting "setButtonTintList" to work.

```
if (Item.getCar()=='Audi'){

int textColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");

//this is what I'm trying to do but setButtonTextList doesn't even show up as an option
radiogroup.setButtonTextList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));

}
```

Comment: Can you post a larger code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample uses `setButtonTextList` not `setButtonTintList`, but changing that alone won't help. `setButtonTintList` can be invoked on a RadioButton, not a RadioGroup. You can either loop through the buttons in your group using `getChildCount` for your total and `getChildAt(i)` to get each radio button and call `setButtonTintList` on each

OR if you have your radio buttons in an xml file you can add the backgroundTint attribute

```
android:backgroundTint="#000000"
```

Note: These will not work for API versions < 21

Comment: This is what I currently have:

                                        int textColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");
     int count = group.getChildCount();
     for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
      group.getChildAt(i).setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));
     }

Comment: And with that latest code, what are you seeing? It's not changing colour or the setButtonTintList still cannot be called?

Comment: If it's the latter, you likely need to cast the child to RadioButton , ((RadioButton) group.getChildAt(i)).setButtonTintList (ColorStateList.valueOf (textColor));

Comment: Yeah, setButtonTintList cannot be called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Thanks for the input.  I got it working with the following:

```
                int textColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");
                int count = radiogroup.getChildCount();
                for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
                    RadioButton x = (RadioButton) radiogroup.getChildAt(i);
                    x.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));
```